# AWS API Gateway SDK, Issues with Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've been trying to use the Android SDK generated by the AWS API Gateway for the past 2 days without much success. I followed the tutorials to create a Simple Calculator using Lambda function, create a Simple Calculator API and intergrate the two.

Using the API console I can test for POST and it works fine, I recieve the correct result providing two numbers and an operation. My issues start when I generate an SDK for Android.

Following this tutorial (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-android.html) I created the .jar files and added them in the "libs" folder in Android Studio along with the dependencies.

However, when I call the "client.rootPost()" method I get an error. Without copying the entire error log the error reads:

```
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientHandler.invoke(ApiClientHandler.java:118)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
        at $Proxy3.execute(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.awstest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
```

My code in the MainActivity looks like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory();
        final SimpleCalculatorAPIClient client = factory.build(SimpleCalculatorAPIClient.class);

        Input body = new Input();
        body.setA(new BigDecimal(1));
        body.setB(new BigDecimal(1));
        body.setOp("+");
        Result output = client.rootPost(body); //LINE 52, where the error points to

        String result = output.getOutput().getC().toString();
    }
```

In my build.gradle I have the following dependencies:

```
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'app/libs')
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.16.11'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core:2.16.11'
```

The last two dependencies are NOT part of the tutorial but I found that I need them in order to call the *"ApiClientFactory"* class from an another question posted here. Which leads me to believe that I'm missing something very obvious regarding this. Following just the above tutorial is not enough and it assumes that you already know some things, which I don't.

Any ideas what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I found what was my problem.

I was getting the error because the code was running on "onCreate", instead it has to run in it's own thread. Example:

```
private void awsTest() {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(10);

                ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory();
                final SimpleCalculatorAPIClient client = factory.build(SimpleCalculatorAPIClient.class);

                Input body = new Input();
                body.setA(new BigDecimal(1));
                body.setB(new BigDecimal(1));
                body.setOp("+");
                Output output = client.rootPost(body);
                Result result = new Result();
                result.setOutput(output);

                String i = result.getOutput().getC().toPlainString();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();
```

}